# FME Counter transformer - Assign a grid with numbers, change order that features are counted

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I have a 100x100 grid made up of square (1x1) polygons. I would like to assign each square a unique number. I have used the Counter transformer in FME, but this assigns the numbers in the grid vertically i.e.

| 1 | 5 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 6 | 10 |
| 3 | 7 | 11 |
| 4 | 8 | 12 |

Whereas I would like to count as follows:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |

If Counter isnt the correct way to approach this, please suggest an alternative transformer!

Comment: 2DGridAccumulator can do this and look at the General section on how to build your columns and rows https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-Transformers/Transformers/2dgridaccumulator.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the counter is fine, you just need to sort the data in a different order. One way to do this is to use the BoundsExtractor to get the min max x y. Then use a Sorter _ymax Numeric Descending and _xmin Numeric Ascending.